# injection of autowired dependencies failed in spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am new to Spring and tying to develop an application. I am getting the error log in catalina as below. I have autowired my controller with service, and service with dao.

### What can be the reason for the exception?----------------------

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.typeset.blog.services.BlogService com.typeset.blog.controllers.MainController.blogService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'blogService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.typeset.blog.dao.BlogDao com.typeset.blog.services.BlogService.dao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'blogDao' defined in file [C:\Users\Rumela\Downloads\blog-engine\blog-with-in-place-comments-master\blog\target\blog-with-comments\WEB-INF\classes\com\typeset\blog\dao\BlogDao.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Unexpected AOP exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'cacheManager' while setting bean property 'cacheManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cacheManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'ehcache' while setting bean property 'cacheManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ehcache' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is net.sf.ehcache.CacheException: java.io.IOException: Access is denied
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 58 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'blogService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.typeset.blog.dao.BlogDao com.typeset.blog.services.BlogService.dao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'blogDao' defined in file [C:\Users\Rumela\Downloads\blog-engine\blog-with-in-place-comments-master\blog\target\blog-with-comments\WEB-INF\classes\com\typeset\blog\dao\BlogDao.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Unexpected AOP exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'cacheManager' while setting bean property 'cacheManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cacheManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'ehcache' while setting bean property 'cacheManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ehcache' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is net.sf.ehcache.CacheException: java.io.IOException: Access is denied
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1127)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1051)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:949)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533)
    ... 60 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.typeset.blog.dao.BlogDao com.typeset.blog.services.BlogService.dao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'blogDao' defined in file [C:\Users\Rumela\Downloads\blog-engine\blog-with-in-place-comments-master\blog\target\blog-with-comments\WEB-INF\classes\com\typeset\blog\dao\BlogDao.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Unexpected AOP exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'cacheManager' while setting bean property 'cacheManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cacheManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'ehcache' while setting bean property 'cacheManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ehcache' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is net.sf.ehcache.CacheException: java.io.IOException: Access is denied
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 71 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'blogDao' defined in file [C:\Users\Rumela\Downloads\blog-engine\blog-with-in-place-comments-master\blog\target\blog-with-comments\WEB-INF\classes\com\typeset\blog\dao\BlogDao.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Unexpected AOP exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'cacheManager' while setting bean property 'cacheManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cacheManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'ehcache' while setting bean property 'cacheManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ehcache' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is net.sf.ehcache.CacheException: java.io.IOException: Access is denied
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:547)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1127)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1051)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:949)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533)
    ... 73 more
Caused by: org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Unexpected AOP exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'cacheManager' while setting bean property 'cacheManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cacheManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'ehcache' while setting bean property 'cacheManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ehcache' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is net.sf.ehcache.CacheException: java.io.IOException: Access is denied
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy.getProxy(CglibAopProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactory.getProxy(ProxyFactory.java:109)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.createProxy(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:447)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:333)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:422)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1571)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    ... 82 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'cacheManager' while setting bean property 'cacheManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cacheManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'ehcache' while setting bean property 'cacheManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ehcache' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is net.sf.ehcache.CacheException: java.io.IOException: Access is denied
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1469)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AbstractBeanFactoryPointcutAdvisor.getAdvice(AbstractBeanFactoryPointcutAdvisor.java:88)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$ProxyCallbackFilter.hashCode(CglibAopProxy.java:939)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer$EnhancerKey$$KeyFactoryByCGLIB$$4ce19e8f.hashCode(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.DefaultNamingPolicy.getClassName(DefaultNamingPolicy.java:39)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.getClassName(AbstractClassGenerator.java:72)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.getClassName(AbstractClassGenerator.java:66)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.generateClass(Enhancer.java:474)
    at org.springframework.cglib.transform.TransformingClassGenerator.generateClass(TransformingClassGenerator.java:33)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:216)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createHelper(Enhancer.java:377)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createClass(Enhancer.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ObjenesisCglibAopProxy.createProxyClassAndInstance(ObjenesisCglibAopProxy.java:57)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy.getProxy(CglibAopProxy.java:202)
    ... 89 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cacheManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'ehcache' while setting bean property 'cacheManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ehcache' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is net.sf.ehcache.CacheException: java.io.IOException: Access is denied
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1469)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
    ... 112 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ehcache' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is net.sf.ehcache.CacheException: java.io.IOException: Access is denied
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1566)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
    ... 122 more
Caused by: net.sf.ehcache.CacheException: java.io.IOException: Access is denied
    at net.sf.ehcache.DiskStorePathManager$DiskStorePath.<init>(DiskStorePathManager.java:331)
    at net.sf.ehcache.DiskStorePathManager.resolveAndLockIfNeeded(DiskStorePathManager.java:145)
    at net.sf.ehcache.DiskStorePathManager.getFile(DiskStorePathManager.java:262)
    at net.sf.ehcache.DiskStorePathManager.getFile(DiskStorePathManager.java:251)
    at net.sf.ehcache.store.disk.DiskStorageFactory.<init>(DiskStorageFactory.java:127)
    at net.sf.ehcache.store.disk.DiskStore.create(DiskStore.java:154)
    at net.sf.ehcache.store.disk.DiskStore.createCacheStore(DiskStore.java:182)
    at net.sf.ehcache.Cache.initialise(Cache.java:1216)
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.initializeEhcache(CacheManager.java:1357)
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.addCacheNoCheck(CacheManager.java:1423)
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.addConfiguredCaches(CacheManager.java:819)
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.doInit(CacheManager.java:498)
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.init(CacheManager.java:394)
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.<init>(CacheManager.java:269)
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.newInstance(CacheManager.java:1103)
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.newInstance(CacheManager.java:1079)
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.create(CacheManager.java:1062)
    at org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(EhCacheManagerFactoryBean.java:144)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1625)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1562)
    ... 129 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Access is denied
    at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
    at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1012)
    at net.sf.ehcache.DiskStorePathManager$DiskStorePath.<init>(DiskStorePathManager.java:322)
    ... 148 more
```

My dispatcher servelet.xml looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:cache="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.1.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/task 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-4.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache-4.1.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.typeset.blog" />
    <cache:annotation-driven />

    <bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager">
        <property name="cacheManager" ref="ehcache" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="ehcache"
        class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:ehcache.xml" />
        <property name="shared" value="true" />
    </bean>

    <context:annotation-config />
    <task:annotation-driven />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:app.properties" />
    <bean id="springDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/blogWithComments" />
        <property name="username" value="***" />
        <property name="password" value="***" />
        <property name="initialSize" value="20" />
        <property name="maxTotal" value="30" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

My dao class looks like this:

```
    @Component
public class BlogDao {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BlogDao.class);

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    public String addBlog(Blog blog){

        String id=Long.toString((long)(Math.abs(UUID.randomUUID().getLeastSignificantBits()/Math.pow(10,11))));
        blog.setId(id);
        Object[] params = new Object[] {id, blog.getTitle(), blog.getPlainText()};      
        int[] types = new int[] { Types.VARCHAR, Types.VARCHAR, Types.VARCHAR};
        int rowsUpdated=jdbcTemplate.update(Constants.ADD_BLOG, params, types);
        DetailedBlog detailedBlog=new DetailedBlog(id, blog.getTitle(), blog.getPlainText());
        int i=0, rowsUpdatedP=0;
        for(Paragraph p:detailedBlog.getParagraphs()){
            params = new Object[] {id, p.getParagraphId(),p.getParagraph()};        
            types = new int[] { Types.VARCHAR, Types.VARCHAR, Types.VARCHAR};
            rowsUpdatedP=jdbcTemplate.update(Constants.ADD_BLOG_PARAGRAPHS, params, types);
            i++;
        }
        if(rowsUpdated==1 && rowsUpdatedP==detailedBlog.getParagraphs().length){
            return Constants.SUCCESS_MESSAGE;
        }
        else
            return Constants.ERROR_MESSAGE;
    }
    @Cacheable("blog_cache")
    public Blog[] getAllBlogs() {
        List<Map<String, Object>> list=jdbcTemplate.queryForList(Constants.GET_ALL_BLOGS);
        Class blogClass=Blog.class;
        Method[] methods = blogClass.getMethods();
        Map<String, Method> map=new HashMap<String, Method>();
        String name="";
        Blog[] blogs=new Blog[list.size()];
        for(Method m:methods){
            name=m.getName();

            //extract all setters
            if(name.contains("set"))
                map.put(name.substring(name.indexOf("set")+3).toLowerCase(), m);
        }
        logger.info("all setters: {}",map);
        int i=0;
        Blog blog=null;
        for(Map<String, Object> row: list){
            logger.info("Row: {}",row);
            blog=new Blog();
            for(String value: row.keySet()){
                try {
                    //populate the pojo
                    if(map.get(value.toLowerCase())!=null)
                        map.get(value.toLowerCase()).invoke(blog, row.get(value));                  
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    logger.error("Error",e);
                }
            }
            logger.info(""+blog);
            blogs[i]=blog;
            i++;
        }
        return blogs;
    }

    public DetailedBlog getDetailedBlog(String id) {
        DetailedBlog detailedBlog=new DetailedBlog();
        detailedBlog.setId(id);
        Map<String, Object> blog=jdbcTemplate.queryForMap(Constants.SELECT_BLOG+id+"'");
        List<Map<String, Object>> paragraphs=jdbcTemplate.queryForList(Constants.SELECT_PARAGRAPHS+id+"'");
        List<Map<String, Object>> comments=jdbcTemplate.queryForList(Constants.SELECT_COMMENTS+id+"'");
        detailedBlog.setTitle((String)blog.get("title"));
        detailedBlog.setPlainText((String)blog.get("plainText"));
        Paragraph para=null;
        List<Paragraph> list=new ArrayList<Paragraph>();
        Map<String,Paragraph> map = new HashMap<String, Paragraph>();
        logger.debug(comments.size()+" "+paragraphs.size());
        if(paragraphs.size()>0){
            for(Map<String, Object> paragraph: paragraphs){
                para=new Paragraph();
                para.setParagraphId((String)paragraph.get("paragraphId"));
                para.setParagraph((String)paragraph.get("paragraph"));
                map.put(para.getParagraphId(), para);
            }
            logger.debug("map "+map.toString());
            for(Map<String, Object> comment: comments){
                para=map.get(comment.get("paragraphId"));
                logger.debug("paragraph "+para.toString());
                List<String> comm=para.getComments();
                if(comm==null){
                    comm=new ArrayList<String>();
                    para.setComments(comm);
                }
                comm.add((String)comment.get("comment"));                           
                logger.debug("comment "+comm.toString());
            }
        }
        logger.debug(map.toString());

        detailedBlog.setParagraphs(map.values().toArray(new Paragraph[0]));
        return detailedBlog;
    }

    public String addComment(String blogId, String paraId, String comment) {
        String id=Long.toString((long)(Math.abs(UUID.randomUUID().getLeastSignificantBits()/Math.pow(10,11))));
        Object[] params = new Object[] {blogId, paraId, id, comment};       
        int[] types = new int[] { Types.VARCHAR, Types.VARCHAR, Types.VARCHAR,Types.VARCHAR};
        int rowsUpdated=0;
        try{
            rowsUpdated=jdbcTemplate.update(Constants.ADD_COMMENT, params, types);
        }catch(Exception e){
            logger.error("error",e);
        }
        if(rowsUpdated==1){
            return Constants.SUCCESS_MESSAGE;
        }
        else
            return Constants.ERROR_MESSAGE;

    }
}
```

Could someone please help me out ?`enter code here`

Comment: `net.sf.ehcache.CacheException: java.io.IOException: Access is denied` thi is the culpit, check the visibility of the fields in the DAO class

Comment: added my dao class

Answer (score 0):

```
at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1012)
```

The method throwing an `Exception` because to create a new File this should have sufficient permissions to create/edit file, And, indeed, you get an error telling you that you don't have permission.

You need to change the Access Control List (ACL) on the directory in which you are creating the file

Answer (score 0):

I would check the ehcache.xml , probably you have there something like

```
<diskStore path="/auto/default/path"/>
```

It looks like the path specified there is incorrect or your user does not have permission to write a file there.